# Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin - Windows 10

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-10, cordova-plugins

I am desperately trying to get an old cordova project up and running as a Windows 10 UAP app. So far it is looking quite well, but a core part of the app is the use of the InAppBrowser of Cordova, and it just does not seem to be working.

#### Versions:

- Cordova: 6.3.1
- cordova windows: 4.4.2
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser:
  1.4.0

So I have managed to build my app using cordova for windows and the Windows 10 SDK. Apart from the plugin it is working fine.

I installed the plugin like it is shown in the documentation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

After that, I wanted to replace window.open by cordova.InAppBrowser.open, also as suggested in the documentation.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

I am calling my links like this:

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'allowInlineMediaPlayback=yes');
```

However, in the Windows 10 app, the sites always get opened in my default browser.

I have already made sure that I do not have any old plugin files in my project.

Is it possible that Windows 10 is not supported yet for the InAppBrowser plugin? Because I can find no specific mentions on the [project page of cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

I would appreciate any kind of hint or solution.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
I just solved it myself :) I found out, that the deviceready has never been triggered. After further investigation I found out that cordova.js was not found. This was due to my folder structure. I had a www folder in the www folder, so I had all the folders like plugins twice. This lead to the problem that MsBuild did not find the cordova.js.

Comment: You mean Windows 10 UWP instead of Windows 10 UAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it myself :) I found out, that the deviceready has never been triggered. After further investigation I found out that cordova.js was not found. This was due to my folder structure. I had a www folder in the www folder, so I had all the folders like plugins twice. This lead to the problem that MsBuild did not find the cordova.js.